# Группировка по пользовательским переменным. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Изучал `MySQL` и задался вопросом о том, что будет при группировке строк по значению, которого нет в используемой таблице, например по пользовательской переменной или константному значению. Допустим есть некоторая таблица `b`. Вот ее структура и содержимое.[image: Структура таблицы b]

Есть переменная `@var`, которая на данный момент равна `1`.
При выполнении этого запроса

`SELECT id, a_id, @var := id
FROM b
GROUP BY @var;`

получается следующий результат:[image: Результат 1-го запроса]

Теперь `@var = 14`. Снова выполняем этот же вопрос.
Вот результат:[image: Результат 2-го запроса]
Строка с `id = 2` переместилась в конец.

Теперь, собственно вопрос.

1. Как MySQL, да и сам стандарт SQL реагирует на группировки по значениям (столбцам), которых нет в таблице (пример `@var`)?
2. Как возможно объяснить такое поведение СУБД? Результат этих запросов будет меняться в зависимости от значения в `@var`.

Прошу меня поправить, если что-то некорректно излагаю. Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандарт SQL определяет синтаксис и не определяет требование к смысловой нагрузке выражения. Использование константы в операторе `group by` не меняет результат (набор записей остается один и тот же) и на практике трудно представить применение такого запроса.

Только `order by` определяет порядок записей, поиск всех других закономерностей пустая трата времени. Без `order by` порядок зависит от тысячи причин: алгоритма, статистики и так далее. Администратор переложил таблицу из одного табличного пространство в другое порядок изменился.